# Arbitrarily oriented minimum area bounding "box" of a polygon on a sphere

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, geodesic-sphere

I would like to calculate an ***arbitrarily oriented*** minimum (area) bounding box of a polygon on a sphere (as a simplification of Earth).
For an axis-aligned version I found [the great example from Jason Davies](https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/bounds/).

The idea is to have as input a list of lon/lat coordinates for the points of the polygon and as output the coordinates of the 4 points (lon/lat) of the bounding box.

**Bonus**: consider the (very likely) cases where the polygon crosses the antimeridian, contains one pole and/or spans more than one hemisphere.

Comment: Transform the points into a coordinate system in which they are axis-aligned with respected to the bounding box orientation; apply the algorithm you found; then transform the 4 corners back into the initial coordinate system.

Comment: Let say I have a polygon, i.e. to simplify mainland Italy (the  concrete and nasty case, is with 2 big islands), and I want to find   a box as describe for it.
How does this fit with your suggestion? Do you say that I rotate each segment and find a axi-aligned BB and take the smallest one?

Comment: What do you mean by a box on a sphere? Do you mean a region bounded between two latitudes and two longitudes?

Comment: See for example [Morocco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morocco). The BB is axis-aligned, but that is not the smallest enclosing box for it.
In fact you could have one a smaller one that goes 45 degrees Sout/West to North/East. HTH.